# magento2 cloud composer.lock file not updated

Tags: magento2.4, composer, magento2-cloud

I am trying to push code from my local to staging and getting the below error. Shouldn't on deploy magento update the composer.lock file based on what's in my json composer file? I am not getting how to add magento/inventory-composer-metapackage to the lock file.

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
    W: - Required package "magento/inventory-composer-metapackage" is not present in the lock file.
```

Answer (score 2):

you should update your dependencies.

try this code

```
composer update
```

If you want to update specific package check this

```
composer update magento/inventory-composer-metapackage
```